# Netlogo: Patches Disappear instantly instead of continualy

Tags: netlogo, patch

I'm trying to show deforestation versus reforestation. To do this I created a slider to show how much reforestarion and deforestation is being done. However every time at 11 ticks the whole scene gets deforestated and I don't know why.

```
patches-own
[reforestar
deforestar]
breed [ potreros potrero ]  ; sheep is its own plural, so we use "a-sheep" as the singular
breed [ bordes borde ]
breed [ bosques bosque ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "frog top"
  
  ask patches 
  [ifelse pcolor = 44
        [ set reforestar tiempo-sin-reforestar ]
    [ set reforestar tiempo-sin-reforestar * 0.5];
  ]
    
  
   
    reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask patches [ reforestacion ]
   ask patches [ deforestacion ]
  
  tick
end

to reforestacion  ; patch procedure
  ; countdown on brown patches: if you reach 0, grow some grass
  if pcolor = 35 [
    ifelse reforestar <= 0
      [ set pcolor 44
        set reforestar tiempo-sin-reforestar ]
      [ set reforestar reforestar - 1 ]
  ]
  
end  
  
to deforestacion
   if pcolor = 44 [
    ifelse deforestar >= 10
      [ set pcolor 35
        set deforestar tasa-deforestacion ]
      [ set deforestar deforestar + 1 ]
  ]
end
```

The idea is that some patches of random brown (deforestacion) turn into yellow (reforestacion) but for some reason it just changes everything at once.

Comment: The code you provided does not reproduce the problem. Please share a version of your code that is both [reproducible and minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're not asking a random number of patches to do something, you're asking all patches with pcolor 44 to count up to 10 with every tick and when they reach 10, they get "deforested".

If you want to ask a random number of patches to get deforested, try something like

```
ask n-of (random ([count patches with pcolor = 44] * deforestationRate)) patches with pcolor = 44 [set pcolor 35 set deforestar tasa-deforestacion]
```

Where deforestationRate would be a value from a slider from 0 to 1. What this would do is count the nuber of patches that can be deforested and then select a random number of those patches to deforest. If you only use the count itself, then every tick between 0 and 100% of the forest will get deforested, but if you add the deforestationRate slider value, it may be whatever maximum percentage you'd like. (So if you set it to 0.1 for example, then only up to 10% of the forest can get deforested each tick) You can do the same thing with reforestation too and use a different slider / value for the rate.

(Note: I haven't used NetLogo in a while so the code and parentheses may not be 100% on point, but you get the idea)