# Netlogo: Set a variable to the number of neighbors of a certain color

Tags: colors, netlogo, patch, nearest-neighbor

im just trying to count the patches that have a certain color and add that count number to a variable. Then, if the number of neighbors crosses a threshold the patch changes color but im getting a Set expected 2 inputs. I think this is a basic question but after reading i dont get the result i need.

```
patches-own
[reforestar
;deforestar
  ;temperatura
;humedad
;dosel
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "frog top"

    ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 30 and
    pxcor >= min-pxcor and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 35 ;
  ]
 ;potrero
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 60 and
    pxcor >= 30 and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 44 ;
  ]
  ;borde
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 90 and
    pxcor >= 60 and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 66 ;
  ]
end
to go
ask patches [ deforestacion ]
end

to potrerizar
 if pcolor = 44 [
    ask patches [ set potrerizado count neighbors with [pcolor = 35] ]]
  
    
end
to deforestacion 
  if potrerizado >= 3 [if random 100 <= tasa-deforestacion 
    [set pcolor = 35]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Beyond not being a reproducible example, this code does not compile in NetLogo and for more than one reason (which is not the thing that you're asking about). As I previously suggested in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544854/netlogo-patches-disappear-instantly-instead-of-continualy), can you please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, especially for what concerns [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Matteo thanks for the help, i corrected the code from my other question but didn't get the result i wanted so im with this one now. Thanks for providing the link and the patience to read all this. Hope the correction is correct.

Comment: I don't see the code edited in the other question, but let's talk about that in that page. As for this question... Thanks for trying to improve your example! However, you should try to provide a piece of code that everyone can just copy+paste in NetLogo to reproduce exactly the type of problem you have. You can try it yourself before posting the question: open a new NetLogo session and copy your code in. In this case, I had to add `end`, to create sliders and guess their values (you can just put them in `globals [...]` in your questions), I even had to re-size the world (the default is 33x33).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `set`, it's indeed because `set` expects two inputs: the variable to set and its new value, without any other sign between these two inputs - [see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set). You had also used it correctly in `to setup`.

In NetLogo, `=` is instead used to evaluate conditions (i.e. it expects two inputs, one on the right and one on the left, and it returns either `true` or `false`). Therefore, writing

```
set pcolor = 35
```

is the same as writing

```
set true   ; if the patch has pcolor = 35, or
set false  ; if the patch has pcolor != 35.
```

none of which makes sense in NetLogo.

---

As for the rest: at the moment, what your code does entirely depends on the value of `potrerizado` that is set in the interface:

1. If it's less than 3, nothing happens;
2. If it's at least 3, patches will have a certain chance of becoming brown (`set pcolor 35`). Which means that, sooner or later, they will all be brown.

In the code, at the moment, `to potrerizar` is never used.

Anyway, I can see that `to potrerizar` asks patches to change `potrerizado`, which is a `global` variable.

Probably what you want is to have `potrerizado` as `patches-own` and not as `global`, but this is just my guess based on what I can see here.

---

Less important, you have some superflous conditions: every patch will always have `pxcor >= min-pxcor` (and similar conditions that you have in `to setup`).

Comment: Matteo thanks for answering! I corrected the error thanks to your comment. After the set error disappear i erased potrerizado that did nothing and put the variable in global and sure thing it work. Thanks for the patience and the help, i know this wont be the last question so see you soon. Have a great day

Comment: @bksnlow Glad it helped - please consider accepting the answer if that's the case